# Does "[noun] of choice" imply the best possible option, or merely *an* option?

Tags: idioms, expressions

If I say something is the "treatment of choice" or the "pencil of choice", etc., does that imply that this is the *best* of all the possible choices available -- that those who *know best* would choose this -- or just that there are many choices available, and this is the one that happens to have been chosen at the moment?

Comment: Free of context, the word *choice* here stands for 'among the best,' derived from the indirect implication that it is the 'option' of the majority, or of those who matter.

Comment: **choice** *adj.*  
**1.** (*esp. of food*) of very good quality.  
"he picked some choice early plums"  
synonyms: *superior, first-class, first-rate, prime, premier, grade A, best, finest, excellent, select, quality, high-quality, top, top-quality, high-grade, prize, fine, special*; (Google)

Comment: Not to be confused with "of one's choice": that one chooses or has chosen: *the college of her choice* (ODO)

Comment: @Kris though "X of choice" could be used that way too, as in, "her college of choice" — the one chosen or her personal favourite, which may not be a universal best.

Comment: @anotherdave *her college of choice* is ambiguous -- use either *the college of choice* or *the college of her choice* to be amply clear. I have mentioned both in my two comments above.

Comment: @Kris I disagree, don't think there's any ambiguity. I've seen it used quite a bit. Reading Game of Thrones at the moment for example — *"He'd had a giant's strength too, his weapon of choice a spiked iron warhammer that Ned could scarcely lift."* (http://tinyurl.com/his-weapon-of-choice
)

Comment: @anotherdave 1. I too disagree with many "pieces of writing advice" and many "grammar rules" so what :) And you do not have to agree at all.

Comment: @Kris Haha, very true! :)

Answer (score 1):

In medicine, the "treatment of choice" is the treatment one chooses based upon a set of criteria determined by a particular patient.  For example, trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole is recommended to the prevention of pneumocystis in patients with HIV disease in patients with a CD4 count <200/µL, but the "treatment of choice" for a patient who is allergic to trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole might be dapsone plus pyrimethamine plus leucovorin.  In the example above, trimethoprim-sulfamethoxazole might be described as the "gold standard," the current and most effective treatment, the one against which dapsone plus pyrimethamine plus leucovorin would have been evaluated.  (Disclaimer: Don't try this at home except under the direct supervision of  . . . .)

Answer (score 1):

I would actually argue that in the construction, "the X *of choice*," *of choice* tends to connote either the most frequently selected option or the best *available* option, rather than the *best* option overall.

For instance, one could write

> For most users, Microsoft Word is the word processor of choice.

That does not mean that Microsoft Word is the best option; it is just the preferred option of those users.

Answer (score 0):

I would draw a distinction between *the* pencil of choice, which is the best, and *a* pencil of choice - one of the best.  From that point of view, the answer to your title is "merely an option" but to the question (which uses "the..." for both examples) -- "the best".  The construction "a [noun] of choice" is less common than "the [noun] of choice".